# Storm Crow 'fiery ball' damage

Tags: diablo-iii

My Storm Crow has a 29% chance to cast a fiery ball when attacking. Does anyone know how much damage the ball does on impact?

Answer (score 1):

To quote the post on [the official blizzard forum](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/storm-crow):

> The Fireball damage is higher than Arcane Orb - Anything damage. He
>   was telling me how his Spark crits for about 6 Million. The Fireball
>   crits about 9 Million for him.

So if we say Arcane Orb does approximately 400% weapon dmg, the fireball would be 400 x 1.5 which is 600% weapon damage. According to this post the Fireball will deal ~500-600% weapon damage

Comment: That quote is from a user comment though. Any slightly more reliable source?

Comment: haven't found anything more reliable, if anyone has that helmet, could the person maybe post damage from a normal spell, from the storm crow proc, and elemental damage?